# Download counter function inaccurate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx

We're using a normal PHP download script (with headers etc) to serve files to users.

The issue however is that with some browsers and large downloads the download script is requested multiple times. NGINX logs show the requests with a 206 status code, (suggesting chunked streaming?) which is strange because we don't serve any streamable content?

Regardless, this means the download script is requested multiple times and thus the MySQL function of +1'ing the download counter for the file is run multiple times per download.

We tried using sessions, but seeing as the download is severed from an external server + domain we have no way to clear said sessions after they're set.

We're using Laravel with NGINX + MySQL, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the spec and the headers for the request which would ultimately result in a 206 response, there was one header which struck out which looks like it would be perfect.

The header in question is the `Content-Range` header which could look like the following:

```
Content-Range: bytes 21010-47021/47022
```

What this is saying is it wants to grab bytes 21010-47021 out of 47022 bytes.  All you should need to be worried about is the first number here and if it's 0 or not.  If the header was set and the first number is 0, you can assume it's just beginning the download and you should increment the counter.